Next. JS 14 and Shadcn-ui set default theme as dark
so i got this error and not have a single idea to solve it. I used chatgpt and codeium, and both are not helping.
error message :
InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('$(dark ? "light" : "dark")') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import MainNav from "@/components/MainNav";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/theme-provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Ticket Application",
  description: "Generated by Vlodex",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider
          attribute="class"
          defaultTheme="dark"
          enableSystem
          disableTransitionOnChange
        >
          <nav className="flex flex-col items-center border-b mb-5 px-5 py-3">
            <div className="max-w-6xl w-full">
              <MainNav />
            </div>
          </nav>
          <main className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <div className="max-w-6xl w-full">{children}</div>
          </main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

and
theme-provider.tsx
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider as NextThemesProvider } from "next-themes";
import { type ThemeProviderProps } from "next-themes/dist/types";

export function ThemeProvider({ children, ...props }: ThemeProviderProps) {
  return <NextThemesProvider {...props}>{children}</NextThemesProvider>;
}


Please help, because I cant continue
I've tried changing the attribute = "class" to "className"
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import MainNav from "@/components/MainNav";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/theme-provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Ticket Application",
  description: "Generated by Vlodex",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider
          attribute="className"
          defaultTheme="dark"
          enableSystem
          disableTransitionOnChange
        >
          <nav className="flex flex-col items-center border-b mb-5 px-5 py-3">
            <div className="max-w-6xl w-full">
              <MainNav />
            </div>
          </nav>
          <main className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <div className="max-w-6xl w-full">{children}</div>
          </main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


it works without an error, but not a dark mode for the default theme.
Thankyou

Please share the code where the error originates? '$(dark ? "light" : "dark")') doesn't exist in the example given
